# Proving set isn't bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I have to Prove that $$A=\left \{\frac{1}{t-3} | t \in (2,4) \setminus  \left\{3\right\} \right \}$$

Isn't bounded.

However in my textbook the proof is a bit complicated, first proving that for every $x \in \Bbb R $ such that $|x|>1, x \in A$.

Any other options here?

Comment: Hint: Take $t=3+1/n$...

Comment: Do you understand why proving that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x|>1\implies x\in A\right)$ implies that $A$ isn't bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ an arbitrary positive real. We have

$$\frac1{t-3}\ge M\iff  (t>3)\wedge (t-3<\frac1M)\iff 3<t\le\frac1M+3$$
so if we choose $t_0=\min(3.5,\frac1M+3)$ the element $a=\frac1{t_0-3}\in A$ and $a\ge M$ and this prove that $A$ isn't bounded above so it isn't bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Just suppose it is bounded above by $M $. Now show that there is some $t \in (2, 4)$\ $\{3\} $ such that

$$\frac{1}{t - 3} > M $$

This means that for every $M $ you pick, there is always a bigger number in $A $, thus $A $ cannot be bounded.

Comment: The second part is unnecessary.

Comment: No, a set is unbounded if it either doesn't have an upper bound or doesn't have a lower bound. $[0,\infty)$, for example, is unbounded.

Comment: @Wojowu my bad then. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Choose K > 1 then $$\frac{1}{t-3} = K \iff \frac{1+3K}{K} = t \iff \frac{1}{K} + 3 = t $$

And for each chosen K then $t \in (3,4) \subseteq (2,4)\setminus\{3\}$ obviously holds so A is unbounded.